# Retrieving Data from sqlite table in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-8

I have a ready database in form of sqlite file from which I want to bind the data with the various controls like combo box, textbox and so on as per the requirement of my app.

I have referred this link : http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/ and created a class as per the table of my database.

I have a table auto_fares and so I have created a class auto_fare. As per mentioned in the link above I have followed the steps mentioned but still I am getting the following error:
"no such table: auto_fares" although a table of this name does exist in my database.

Please guide me. Any help is welcomed.
Awaiting replies.

The following the block of code:

```
StorageFile seedFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(
    Path.Combine(
       Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path,
       "fare.sqlite"));
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("fare.sqlite");
var query = conn.Table<auto_fares>();
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in result)
{
   auto_fares obj = new auto_fares();
   cbCity.Items.Add(item.city);
}
```

Comment: It appears you have a new, empty database. Please show the code that tries to open the database, and where you've put the file.

Comment: @CL.Please find the edited question with code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default path is `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` (and your code never uses `seedFile` anyway).

See [Seeding your Metro style app with a SQLite database](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/06/28/seeding-your-metro-style-app-with-sqlite-database.aspx).

Comment: Now I am able to retrieve the data as I read the pose mentioned by @CL. Thanks for that. I had one doubt. Can you please guide on how to copy my existing database in my application in a simple manner. I read this entire article but still have a doubt in my mind. Thanks in advance.